# Why use a bitwise not in MIPS instead of using exactly value?

Tags: assembly, gcc, mips

I'm trying to learn MIPS assembly, but I'm a bit confused about an example of MIPS assembly I have found.

```
#Socket Domain - AF_INET (2)
li $t4, 0xFFFFFFFD #-3
not $a0, $t4
#Socket Type - SOCK_STREAM (2 for mips)
not $a1, $t4
#Socket Protocol - 0
slti $a2, $zero, 0xFFFF
#Call socket
li $v0, 4183
syscall 0x42424
```

For the socket() syscall, there are 3 arguments. The first argument being AF_INET or 2, why does the example above not just use `li $a0, 2` instead of:

```
li $t4, 0xFFFFFFFD #-3 
not $a0, $t4
```

The line below is also used, what is the purpose of this with regards to the socket called?

```
slti $a2, $zero, 0xFFFF
```

Is this just the way the assembly has been 'optomized' by GCC? Or is their a reason?

Comment: Is this possibly shellcode? You usually want to avoid zero bytes in those. It's likely hand coded not compiler generated.

Comment: The MIPS processor doesn't have a `not` machine code instruction.  The two-operand `not` is a pseudo instruction: it gets translated by the assembler into machine code to a  three-operand `nor` with $0.